# What's with the \\ in Windows network share paths?

Tags: windows, network-shares, file-sharing

Paths to Windows network shares start with a `\\`. Does anyone know why (already tried The Great Mighty Google)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s simply how the so-called [Uniform Naming Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) is made to be.

A more formal definition is available [from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx):

```
UNC                = "\\" host-name "\" share-name  [ "\" object-name ]
 host-name          = "[" IPv6address ‘]" / IPv4address / reg-name  
    ; IPv6address, IPv4address, and reg-name as specified in [RFC3986] 
 share-name         = 1*80pchar
 pchar              = %x20-21 / %x23-29 / %x2D-2E / %x30-39 / %x40-5A / %x5E-7B / %x7D-FF  
 object-name        = *path-name [ "\" file-name ]
 path-name          = 1*255pchar
 file-name          = 1*255fchar [ ":" stream-name [ ":" stream-type ] ]
 fchar              = %x20-21 / %x23-29 / %x2B-2E / %x30-39 / %x3B / %x3D / %x40-5B / %x5D-7B /                            %x7D-FF 
 stream-name        = *schar
 schar              = %x01-2E / %x30-39 / %x3B-5B /%x5D-FF
 stream-type        = 1*schar
```

It’s basically something of an identifier saying “Here’s a UNC identifier”.

Comment: ...and other (Unix) systems used a similar convention with forward slashes before Microsoft Windows was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

It's called UNC (Universal Naming Convention).The double slash at the beginning is just a format.

Answering why the format is the way it is would be like trying to answer why Local Paths have a drive letter followed by a colon (:) followed by a forward slash ().